# Priority of certain Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following cells that could hold the following values based on other formulas..

```
L:31 None, Yellow, Green
M:31 None, Yellow, Green
```

I need cell N:31 to show a certain priority level depending on the contents of the prior cells. The logic is as follows:

1. If either of the two cells (L:31 and M:31) show None, print None in N:31
2. After that check, if any of the cells (L:31 and M:31) show Yellow, even if the other cell is 'Green', print Yellow in N:31.
3. And finally, that means if BOTH cells (L:31 and M:31) show Green, Green would be printed.

I have tried many different formula's and it's making me go crazy!

ex #2

```
L:31 Yellow
M:31 None
 N:31 None
----
L:31 Green
M:31 Yellow
 N:31 Yellow
----
L:31 Green
M:31 Green
 N:31 Green
----
L:31 None
M:31 Green
 N:31 None
```

Comment: What formulas have you tried? Did they work? Did they return an error?

Comment: Many were erased due to frustration. I had a long winded chain of IF commands at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the examples provided:

```
=IF(OR(L31="None",M31="None"),"None",IF(OR(L31="Yellow",M31="Yellow"),"Yellow","Green"))
```

It could perhaps be shortened a little but I chose to try and keep to your description of the requirement.

IF 'short circuits' - once either cell is `None` then you don't need to worry further about it combining with `Yellow` or `Green`.

Comment: I see where my error was; Thanks! Worked like a charm.